# Running a java function on a reoccurring date

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I am running a Java spring web application on a server and I need to run some of my functions every night automatically. Since this is a web app, the program is running 24/7 on the server. How can I schedule some of my functions to run every night at 7pm?

Comment: You could read through https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/ or just cron the wicked thing

Comment: You can use cron if you're running on linux server, or quartz library with cron trigger if you're running on windows

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting. Scheduling a task with Spring has been covered many many times already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spring's `@EnableScheduling` (In you `main` class) and `@Scheduled` (on the method that you need to trigger) annotations. You can use cron expressions inside `@Scheduled`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html